# Multiple versions of same app, swagger UI is not giving both endpoints which of same endpoint and operation ID

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui

I was trying to generate two different models for an application, which has different versions with same endpoint names and operation id like below.
after search, learnt adding **x-version: "v2"** shall give two endpoints of same name in swagger ui, but didn't work.

-> Can I use a app with different versions ( though changes are in small text as well, with
similar structure of endpoint name , operation id) ?

-> I want to see both names in swagger ui.

-> generation using python-flask
below is similar example:

```yaml
# Example YAML file
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "RP Flask REST API"
  description: "An API about people and notes"
  version: "1.0.0"

servers:
  - url: "/api"

paths:
  /people:
    get:
      operationId: "people.read_all"
      x-version: "v1"
      tags:
        - "People"
      summary: "Read the list of people"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully read people list"
          
  /people:
    get:
      operationId: "people.read_all"
      x-version: "v2"
      tags:
        - "People"
      summary: "Read the list of people"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully read people list"
    put:
      operationId: "people.read_all"
      x-version: "v2"
      tags:
        - "People"
      summary: "write the list of people"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully written people list"
'''
```